# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}$ where $\vert z\vert = 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series

We were asked to study the convergence of this series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}$$ 
on the boundary of its convergence disc i.e.: $\vert z\vert = 1$

And a friend argumented something like this:
As $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, by Abel's theorem([click here for the link of its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)), we can argue:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}\biggr) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

But I don't really know how that answers the question of how the series behaves on its convergence disc boundary anyways? Or have I understood something wrong about Abel's theorem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lvert z\rvert=1$, then $\left\lvert\dfrac{z^{n!}}{n^2}\right\rvert=\dfrac1{n^2}$. Since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges, your series converges absolutely. In particular, it converges. You don't need Abel's theorem at all.

Comment: Oh, you're right, there's no need for all of that, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's argument is nonsense. First, the term

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}\biggr)$$

does not make sense, as $n$ is no longer a free variable outside the sum, so there is no $n$ to take the limit of. But this may just be a typo by you or them.

More importantly, the Abel theorem says that your sum has some continuity properties at $z=1$, it doesn't say anything about any other place on the boundary of the unit disc.

Comment: Noo, it wasn't a typo and wow, I didn't even think that it didn't even make sense to take the limit, thanks!